# An attempt to mix objects belonging to different transactions

Tags: orm, ponyorm

`pony.orm.core.TransactionError: An attempt to mix objects belonging to different transactions`

I know that this error is descriptive, I just can't figure out WHY its occurring. I have searched google, the docs, other SO posts, and found nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error arises if somebody attempts to interlink two objects which belongs to identity maps of two different db sessions:

```py
from pony.orm.examples.university1 import *

populate_database()

with db_session:
    g = Group[101]

with db_session:
    s = Student[4]
    s.group = g  # or g.students.add(s)
```

Each db session should work with objects retrieved within this db session only. If you need to store some information between db sessions, you can store object's `id` value instead of object itself. Also you can pickle objects in one `db_session` and then unpickle them in another `db_session`.