# Attempt to mix objects belonging to different transactions with independent db_sessions

Tags: python, python-3.x, ponyorm

I'm getting this error in `func2` below:

`pony.orm.core.TransactionError: An attempt to mix objects belonging to different transactions`

I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225518/an-attempt-to-mix-objects-belonging-to-different-transactions), but the accepted answer doesn't apply to me. I am not reusing an object from another db_session. I have 2 db_sessions in succession that are in fact in completely different functions:

```py
def func1():
    with db_session:
        # Self contained operation
    return

def func2():
    with db_session:
        # Different self contained operation
    return

def main():
    func1()
    func2()
```

I am not passing any arguments from the first function to the second; they are completely decoupled. It was my understanding that once a db_session context is exited, the transaction commits. A new db_session starts a new identity map and transaction, so there should be no lingering ORM dependency between these two function calls.

If I just run `func2()`, it runs fine. It only seems to throw the exception when it follows the call to `func1()`.

Can someone explain how transactions could be mixed if they are independent transactions with no shared data? How can the first db_session still be affecting the second one? What context is Pony still maintaining between db_sessions?

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

Deep inside `func1` there was a function decorated with `lru_cache` that returned an Entity instance. `func2` would read the same Entity in a new transaction, but the LRU Cache was returning a cached version that was attached to the previous `db_session`.

When I cleared the cache after `func1`, the error went away:

```py
def main():
    func1()
    cached_func.cache_clear() # <- Clear Cache
    func2()
```

Lesson learned: Be mindful of caches when running multiple separate db_sessions. They can introduce hidden object mixing.